How to reactively display websocket.readyState in vue3?
I want to display websocket.readyState in component reactively. But it doesn't change the display status in a timely manner. It always change display at next time.
The code can't work properly:
let ws = ref(null);
ws.value = new WebSocket('url');

<template>
    <div>{{ ws.readyState }}</div>
</template>

If there is a interval in the same component, it will works properly.
let time = ref('');
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    time.value = moment(time.value).add(1, 's').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}, 1000);

<template>
    <div>{{ time }}</div>
    <div>{{ ws.readyState }}</div>
</template>

I guess interval trigger the view update, but why did the ws itself not trigger an update?
In addition, i has tried let status = toRef(ws.value, 'readyState') and let { readyState } = toRefs(ws.value), but neither of them works.
I want to know why it can't display reactively and how to resolve it? Is it related to the responsive principle of Vue3?
Thanks!

I prefer useWebSocket in vueuse

I guess websockets, for whatever technical reason, aren't reactive.  If you view the code of useWebSocket mentioned above, they separately track the websocket status using a ref, updating it when certain events occur (e.g. onopen, onclose).  You can do the same.
